# Аутентификация в приложении

Tags: android, java, шифрование

Есть приложение и есть сервис аутентификации в сети. Хочу сделать правильно аутентификацию на нем, что бы человек введя один раз логин и пароль, не вводил его потом еще раз. В связи с чем есть несколько вопросов.

1)Как правильно сделать - отдельную активити на которой запрашивается логин и пароль, а потом перенаправляется на основную или на главной менять лайаут в зависимости от того, авторизован человек или нет?

2)Как хранить пароль и логин пользователя? Его можно зранить в базе, но это не очен хорошо, т.к. он будет в этом случае хранится в открытом виде. Хранить же просто признак того, что пользователь прошел авторизацию считаю тоже не совсем верно.

Кто сталкивался с подобными задачами, поделитесь опытом.

Comment: Вопрос хороший, только почему вы думаете, что пароль будет храниться в открытом виде только в базе? Его можно зашифровать и поместить куда угодно, а можно шифровать и куда бы вы его не девали, он все равно будет в открытом виде.

Comment: Не совсем Вас понял. Я должен передать не шифрованный пароль на вход сервису. В связи с чем я могу использовать для шифрования лишь двунаправленные алгоритмы, которые уязвимы по определению и где бы я его не хранил в базе, файле или как то иначе его можно будет всегда прочесть, разве нет?

Comment: А сервис аутентификации ваш?

Comment: может я и неправ, но, мне кажется шифровать данные у себя на телефоне - это небольшая, но паранойя, т.е. если сервис аутентификации уже готовый, вероятнее всего он поддерживает сервис "римемберМи", т.е. помнит юзера и пускает его по кукам, так как пароль все равно надо будет слать сервису пост-запросом в нешифрованом виде, хранить его на девайсе шифрованым - лишнее.

Comment: сервер аутификации мой. Т.е. Вы предлагаете хранить на телефоне пароль в нешифрованном виде и признак того что аутификация была пройдена успешна, для того что бы работать оффлайн. Как только инет появился отсылать нешифрованный пароль на сервак и "уточнять" актуален ли все еще он? 

Почему шифровать данные на телефоне не гут? Ведь есть  javax.crypto.Cipher, как я понимаю он полностью реализует функционал стандартного DES алгоритма.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно делается так:

1. Есть активити аутентификации -
       где юзер вводит логин/пароль
2. Есть глобальная переменная которая
       показывает авторизован юзер или нет.
3. Если переменная показывает, что
       юзер неавторизован производится
       перенаправление на активити
       аутентификации, иначе продолжается
       нормальная работа
4. В БД логин/пароль естественно не хранится
       :) Надо хранить хэш пароля или пары
       логин/пароль. При аутентификации
       вычисляется хэш пароля и
       сравнивается с сохраненными данными.

Одной из уязвимых точеки такой схемы является - глобальная переменная которая показывает авторизован юзер или нет. Надо предпринимать специальные меры по ее защите - ну например привязкой ее к хэшу, времени, вычислением через шифрование и проч.

Comment: 4) Наверное здесь путаница произошла. У меня есть две бд, одна на стороне сервера, там разумеется хранится хеш пароля хранится, но на стороне приложения если я буду хранить например md5 хеш, то я не смогу востановить пароль для отправки его серверу.

за объяснение по активити - спасибо, так и сделаю.

Comment: Не понимаю, а зачем хранить хэш пароля локально? Ну выдал вам юзер при входе пароль - сразу же его отсылайте на удаленный сервер. Или я еще чего то не понимаю?

Comment: @DeMoGargon, вы после регистрации пользователя больше не пользуетесь паролями для сравнения. Вы всегда теперь должны использовать хэш (так как и на клиенте и на сервере вы имеет возможность получить этот самый хэш).

Т.е. клиент отправляет хэш (имя польз. + пароль), сервер принимает, сравнивает со тем, что получается у него от тех же переменных.